# Writing count aggregate function in many to many relationship in JPA throwing Hiberate errors

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities (Order and Product) that have a many to many relationship with each other through a link table. I need to return all the orders in which the number of products in an order > 2. My Model is given below

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class Order implements Serializable {

   public static final int PRECISION = 2;

   @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @JsonIgnore
  private String orderId;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL)
  @JoinTable(
        name = "order_product",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", updatable = false, nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
)
  @JsonBackReference
  private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

. . . . Getters and Setters

}
```

Products

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String productId;

    @JoinTable(name = "order_product", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Order> orders;

    . . . Getters and setters . . .

}
```

I want to fetch all the orders along with their products in which number of orders in a the product is greater than 2.

I have tried multiple variations of the same query. (Check the commented ones)

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Serializable> {

  //@Query("SELECT o from Order o INNER JOIN o.products GROUP BY o.orderId HAVING count(o.products) > 2")
  //@Query("select o from Orders o join o.products p GROUP BY o.orderId HAVING COUNT(p) > 2")
  @Query("SELECT o from Order o join o.products p having count(p) > 2")
  List<Order> findOrderWithMultipleProducts();
}
```

If I have modelled my domains incorrectly, then please let me know.

One of the errors that I get is

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: having near line 1, column 70 [SELECT o from com.jpa.orders.domain.Order o join o.products p having count(p) > 2]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE size(o.products) > 2")
```

Regarding fetching the products alongside the order, I usually use @NamedEntityGraph for that. In your case put something like this on top of your Order entity:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "OrderWithProducts",
    attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value="products")
    }
)
```

Then add this to your Repository method:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "OrderWithProducts" , type=EntityGraphType.FETCH)
```

This will join the entities and will fetch your data using one query. Of course you always want to look at what SQL Hibernate generates for you and optimize according to your needs.

Comment: There is a many to many relationship between the two. Which one is the parent in this case?

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Hmm, let me see if I can find something for you.

Comment: This blogpost seems to cover the subject quite well: http://springquay.blogspot.nl/2016/01/new-approach-to-solve-json-recursive.html